# Where does checkbox store the report?

Tags: 17.04, checkbox

I've ran checkbox to test my system.

I got 2 failed tests, but it doesn't say what failed.

I clicked on "Save detailed report" - where does it save it to?

I'm not connected to the internet on that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox saves its reports to the Documents folder of the current user (`/home/user/Documents`) in both HTML and XLSX format.

In my test, the resulting reports were named `submission_2017-06-28T15:29:16.974627.html` and `submission_2017-06-28T15:29:17.118216.xlsx`, both saved in `/home/richbl/Documents`.